# Generator loss not decreasing while training GAN

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, image-generation, generator

I’ve been attempting to create a basic GAN to generate images using this database of flowers ([https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/flowers/102/](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/flowers/102/)).

I’ve spent a few days on this, and largely based my design on the PyTorch DCGAN documentation (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html). However, no matter how I tune the hyper parameters, my discriminator is always reaching a super high accuracy while the generator can never significantly decrease its loss.

I am using an Adam Optimizer and a BCELoss function. I’ve tuned the learning rate multiple times. Right now, my generator has a learning rate of 0.00005 and the discriminator has a learning rate of 0.0002.

How do I allow the generator to decrease its loss?

````
import random
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as tt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import cv2
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.utils import save_image
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np

# Set random seed for reproducibility
manualSeed = 999
#manualSeed = random.randint(1, 10000) # use if you want new results
print("Random Seed: ", manualSeed)
random.seed(manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(manualSeed)
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True) # Needed for reproducible results

DATA_DIR = "main_data/" 

image_size = 64 # signficantly reduces size
batch_size = 64
stats = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) # normalizes values between -1-1, makes it more convenient for discriminator training

# number of channels in the iamge
nc = 3
latent_size = 100 #input "noise" vector size

# size of feature map in generator
ngf = 64

# size of feature map in discriminator
ndf = 64

training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(DATA_DIR, transform = tt.Compose([
    tt.Resize(image_size), # resizes it to 'image_size'
    tt.CenterCrop(image_size),
    tt.ToTensor(),
    tt.Normalize(*stats) # normalizes values between -1-1, makes it more convenient for discriminator training
])) # check if you need crop + resize
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True) # batches training_dataset up and makes it iterable
device = torch.device("mps") 
print(device)

# displqy plot 
example_batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8)) # 8 by 8 grid
plt.title("Training Images")
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(make_grid(example_batch[0].to(device)[:64], padding=2, normalize=True).cpu(),(1,2,0)))
# plt.show()

# custom weights initialization called on ``netG`` and ``netD``
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

class Generator(nn.Module):
    """This class is the template for our generator module"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(

            #in = 128 x 1 x 1
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(latent_size, ngf * 8, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False), # upscales image  (can cause artifacts, look into this)
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8), # normalizes data
            nn.ReLU(True), # activation function that turns 0s into 1s
            # out = 512 x 4 x 4
        
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias = False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # out = 512 x 8 x 8

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, kernel_size=4, stride = 2, padding = 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # out = 128 x 16 x 16

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, kernel_size=4, stride = 2, padding = 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # out = 64 x 32 x 32

            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, nc, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh(),
            # out = 3 (RGB channels) x 64 (size) x 64 (size)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x).to(device)
        return output

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    """Module for discriminator"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            # in 3 x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out: 64 x 32 x 32

            nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out = 128 x 16 x 16

            nn.Conv2d(ndf*2, ndf * 4, kernel_size = 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out = 256 x 8 x 8

            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # out = 512 x 4 x 4

            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, 1, kernel_size=4, stride = 1, padding=0, bias=False),
            # out = 1 x 1 x 1

            nn.Sigmoid(), # activation

            nn.Flatten()
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.model(x).to(device)
        return output

generator = Generator().to(device=device)
generator.apply(weights_init)
print(generator)

discriminator = Discriminator().to(device=device)
discriminator.apply(weights_init)
print(discriminator)

sample_dir = 'generated'
os.makedirs(sample_dir, exist_ok=True)
def save_samples(index, latent_tensors, show=True):
    fake_images = generator(latent_tensors)
    fake_fname = 'generated-image-{}.png'.format(index)
    save_image(fake_images, os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_fname), nrow=8)
    print(f"Saving {fake_fname}")
    if show:
        fig, ax = plt.subplot(figsize =(8,8))
        ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.imshow(make_grid(fake_images.cpu().detach(), n_row = 8).permute(1,2,0))
        plt.show()

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
def train_discriminator(real_images, opt_d):
    discriminator.zero_grad() # zeroes out gradient from previous iter

    # pass real image through discrimiantor
    real_image_pred = discriminator(real_images)
    actual_answer = torch.ones(real_images.size(0), 1, device=device) # size: real_image.size(0) x 1 of ones 
    # loaded onto device
    real_loss = criterion(real_image_pred, actual_answer)
    real_score = torch.mean(real_image_pred).item() # average of all the prediction is the accuracy (since all of them should be 1)
    # Update discriminator weight
    real_loss.backward()

    # Generate fake image
    latent = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_size, 1, 1, device=device) # size: batch_size x latent_size x 1 x 1
    fake_images = generator(latent)

    # Pass fake image through discriminator
    fake_image_pred = discriminator(fake_images.detach())
    actual_answer = torch.zeros(fake_images.size(0), 1, device=device) # a vector of all 0s
    fake_loss = criterion(fake_image_pred, actual_answer)
    fake_loss.backward()
    fake_score = 1 - torch.mean(fake_image_pred).item()

    # Update discriminator weight
    opt_d.step()

    # loss and accuracy of discriminator on real images, fake images, and  generator
    return real_loss, fake_loss, real_score, fake_score



def train_generator(opt_g):
    generator.zero_grad() # zeroes out gradient from previous iter

    # Generate fake image
    latent = torch.randn(batch_size, latent_size, 1, 1, device=device) # size: batch_size x latent_size x 1 x 1
    fake_images = generator(latent)

    # Try to fool the discriminator
    fake_image_pred = discriminator(fake_images) # the exact same thing as before but without the detach
    targets = torch.ones(batch_size, 1, device=device)
    gen_loss = criterion(fake_image_pred, targets)
    gen_score = torch.mean(fake_image_pred).item()
    
    # Update generator weights
    gen_loss.backward()
    opt_g.step()

    return gen_loss, gen_score

fixed_latent = torch.randn(1, latent_size, 1, 1, device = device)

def fit(epochs, lr_g, lr_d, start_idx = 1):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache() #Releases all unoccupied cached memory currently held by the caching allocator so that those can be used in other GPU application and visible in nvidia-smi.
    size = len(train_dataloader)
   
    # Create optimizer
    opt_d = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr = lr_g, betas = (0.5, 0.999)) # Betas are used as for smoothing the path to the convergence also providing some momentum to cross a local minima or saddle point.
    opt_g = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr = lr_d, betas = (0.5, 0.999))
    for epoch in range(epochs):
         #Losses and scores
        loss_discriminator = 0
        discriminator_scores_on_real = 0
        discriminator_scores_on_fake = 0
        loss_generator = 0
        gen_scores = 0

        print(f"Epoch {epoch}\n----------------------")
        # Train discriminator
        for batch_num, (images,_ ) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            print(f"{batch_num}/{size}")
            # Discriminator train
            real_images = images.to(device)
            real_loss, fake_loss, real_score, fake_score = train_discriminator(real_images, opt_d)
            
            # Record losses and scores of discriminator
            loss_discriminator += (real_loss + fake_loss)/2 # loss on fake and real images / 2
            discriminator_scores_on_real += real_score
            discriminator_scores_on_fake += fake_score

            # Generator train
            gen_loss, gen_score = train_generator(opt_g)

            # Record losses and scores of generator
            loss_generator += gen_loss
            gen_scores += gen_score

        # Log losses & scores (last batch)
        print(f"loss_d_average: {loss_discriminator/128:.4f}, discriminator_scores_on_real: {discriminator_scores_on_real/128:.4f}, discriminator_scores_on_fake: {discriminator_scores_on_fake/128:.4f}")
        print(f"loss_g average: {loss_generator/128:.4f}, generator_score: {gen_scores/128:.4f}")

        # Save generated images
        save_samples(epoch+start_idx, fixed_latent, show=False)

    return loss_generator, loss_discriminator

hitory = fit(600, 0.00005, 0.0002)
 ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking too much at the code, as this is not a place to ask debugging questions, I'll give some advice on how to potentially solve your problems. I'll assume your code is operational (its always good to recheck your preprocessing steps, and see if your generator operates in the same space as your data).

You state that the generator can never converges and that your discriminator is always overpowering your generator. This is a common problem, and there are several ways to potentially solve it. We have to get to a state where your discriminator and generator are 'balanced', so either we have to make your discriminator worse, or your generator better.

1. You can play around with the learning rate. You can increase the generator learning rate, and decrease the discriminator learning rate.
2. You can play around with the architecture itself. Often, you can make your discriminator architecture a smaller (2 layers instead of 4, less filters, smaller kernels, etc) than your generator architecture. This again has influence on your learning rate, so you might need to adjust that then.
3. You can make your discriminator operationally worse by removing batchnormalization layers. As you've seen, the discriminator is not the bottleneck, so we can make it worse. If your model converges, you can start adding stuff back up.

It's always a balancing game, so you're going to have to play around with it.